# Mostrar Dialog desde Cardview Android Java

Tags: java, android-studio, recyclerview, cardview

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación donde estoy utilizando RecyclerView y CardView para mostrar un listado de comidas las cuales previamente han sido añadidos por el usuario y se encuentran en la BD de SQLite. Lo que estoy intentando realizar es que al momento de dar clic sobre cualquiera de ellos se muestre una nueva ventana con más detalles de la comida, he intentado mostrar otro activity como Dialog para ver si funcionaba antes de realizar el diseño como tal, pero la aplicación se detiene al pulsar sobre el cardview. A continuación les presento mi código:

**AdapterList:**

```
package com.example.project_final.views;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.project_final.R;
import com.example.project_final.dto.mealUser;


import java.util.List;

public class AdapterListMeals extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterListMeals.mealViewHolder> {
    private List<mealUser> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context context;
    private Dialog mydialog;


    public AdapterListMeals(List<mealUser> itemList, Context context) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.mData = itemList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() { return mData.size(); }

    @Override
    public AdapterListMeals.mealViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.meal_element_list, null);
        AdapterListMeals.mealViewHolder  myViewHolder = new AdapterListMeals.mealViewHolder(view,context);

        mydialog = new Dialog(context);
        mydialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_meal_detail);

            myViewHolder.meal_element.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"clic normal",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mydialog.show();
            }
        });

        myViewHolder.meal_element.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"clic sostenido x2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //return true;
                return false;
            }
        });
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdapterListMeals.mealViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.cv.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_transition));
        holder.bindData(mData.get(position));
    }

    public void setItems(List<mealUser> items) { mData = items; }

    public class mealViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        Context context;
        ImageView iconImage;
        TextView name, days, hour;
        CardView cv;
        RelativeLayout meal_element;

        Dialog mydialog;

        mealViewHolder(View itemView, Context c) {
            super(itemView);
            iconImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_meal_type);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txv_meal_mame);
            days = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txv_meal_days);
            hour = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txv_meal_hour);
            meal_element = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rlt_meal_element);
            cv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            this.context = c;
            mydialog = new Dialog(context);
        /*meal_element.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Dialog mydialog = new Dialog(v.getContext());
                mydialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_meal_detail);
                mydialog.show();
                Toast.makeText(context,"clic normal",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        meal_element.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"clic sostenido x2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });*/
        }

        void bindData(final mealUser item) {
            String nColor ="#ffffff";
            String day1 = context.getResources().getString(R.string.meal_txv_day1);
            String day2 = context.getResources().getString(R.string.meal_txv_day2);
            String day3 = context.getResources().getString(R.string.meal_txv_day3);
            String day4 = context.getResources().getString(R.string.meal_txv_day4);
            String day5 = context.getResources().getString(R.string.meal_txv_day5);
            String day6 = context.getResources().getString(R.string.meal_txv_day6);
            String day7 = context.getResources().getString(R.string.meal_txv_day7);

            String ls_days = "";
            if(item.getDays().indexOf("|1") > -1) ls_days = day1+" ";
            if(item.getDays().indexOf("|2") > -1) ls_days = ls_days+day2+" ";
            if(item.getDays().indexOf("|3") > -1) ls_days = ls_days+day3+" ";
            if(item.getDays().indexOf("|4") > -1) ls_days = ls_days+day4+" ";
            if(item.getDays().indexOf("|5") > -1) ls_days = ls_days+day5+" ";
            if(item.getDays().indexOf("|6") > -1) ls_days = ls_days+day6+" ";
            if(item.getDays().indexOf("|7") > -1) ls_days = ls_days+day7+" ";
            ls_days = ls_days.trim();
            ls_days = ls_days.replace(" ","-");

            if(item.getType_meal().equals("1")) {
                iconImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_free_breakfast_24);
                meal_element.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_back_breakfast));
            }else if(item.getType_meal().equals("2")) {
                iconImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_fastfood_24);
                meal_element.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_back_lunch));
            }else if(item.getType_meal().equals("3")) {
                iconImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_local_dining_24);
                meal_element.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_back_dinner));
            }

            iconImage.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#000000"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            name.setText(item.getName());
            days.setText(ls_days);
            hour.setText(item.getHour());
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity con el que estoy intentando mostrar:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.circularreveal.CircularRevealRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="HOLA MUNDO"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</com.google.android.material.circularreveal.CircularRevealRelativeLayout>
```

Al darle debug, justo cuando paras por el mydialog.show(), refleja el siguiente error:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

Investigando el error entiendo que se debe a que el Dialog se esta levantando sobre un Activity que esta por finalizar, por lo que indago que puede ser el por **context** talvez, el cual lo obtengo a través de la actividad que contiene el RecyclerView por el método getAplicationContext().

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución simple puede ser pasarle la **activity** en el *constructor*, como por ejemplo

```
   Activity activity;

    public AdapterListMeals(List<mealUser> itemList, Context context, Activity activity) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.mData = itemList;
        this.activity = activity;
    }
```

Ahora usa **activity** y no *context* para el *dialog*, y donde lo llamas le pasas la clase, ya no deberías tener problemas.
Otra opción es usar **broadcast**, así no abres el *dialog* en el *adapter*, sino en la activity.

Comment: Excelente, si me funciono y también revisaré lo otra opción del broadcast. Podrías explicar por que es necesario enviar la actividad y no el context?? no entiendo muy bien esa parte. Gracias

Comment: Genial! Un adapter no puede mostrar un dialog, ya que el adapter lo está creando la activity, el context viene del adapter, necesitabas el de la activity.